# What's the best way to get Attribute value with Reflection in Java

Tags: java, object, reflection

I know i can get the attribute names, types, and set their values from an Object.

I wanna know what's the best way to get their values via reflections.

EDIT:
For meaning. Best is like, less code, less memory and faster execution.

Like:
Is it better if I try to invoke the methods to get their values, or if I use something like this:

```
Object obj;
Class cls = obj.getClass();
cls.getField("atribute1").get(obj).toString();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? What _objective_ measure are you using to compare methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I know of to do that is to use [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/)